# Understanding Moq's Setup() function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I have some confusion with `Setup()`.

From my understanding when we declare:

```
Mock<IUnitOfWork> uwork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
```

We are creating a mock repository that will never *actually* reach-out to a database. Since it never touches the database we have to give it some mock data.

**For example:**

```
Question question = new Question {
    Title = "General question",
    Message = "Message body text..."
}
```

Here's where I'm a bit confused. From my understanding we are telling our Mocked repository *what* data to return and under *which* circumstance to return it.

```
                   // in this circumstance         // return this
uwork.Setup(i =. i.QuestionsRepository.GetById(1)).Returns(question)
```

At this point we create an instance of our controller and pass **uwork.object** to the controller instance. When the controller calls the (circumstance) method, our Mock repository produces the return value we specified.

### Question

Is this correct? *If not* stop me here and correct me. *If so*, then why doesn't something like this work and how do I resolve this?

**Controller:**

```
uwork.QuestionRepository.GetAll().Where(l => l.Message_Id == id).ToList();
```

**TestController:**

```
uwork.Setup(i => i.QuestionsRepository
        .GetAll().Where(l => l.Message_Id == 1).ToList())
        .Returns(questions); 
        // questions is a List<Question>
```

**I get an exception:**

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   Moq.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Expression references a method that does not
>   belong to the mocked object: i =>
>   i.LegalInquiryRepository.GetAll().Where(l =>
>   l.legalCommunication_Id ==

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting that exception because you're trying to set up a method (`Where`) that does *not* belong to the mock (`uwork`).

You need to first setup the `i.QuestionRepository` property, then the `GetAll` method.

The `Where` method (assuming it's the one defined for `IQueryable`) cannot be mocked because it's static - but that's ok. Just make sure that the source collection has the correct elements, and `Where` will select them.

```
var questionsRepoMock = //...

uwork.SetupGet(i => i.QuestionsRepository).Returns(questionsRepoMock.Object);


questionsRepoMock.Setup(r => r.GetAll())
                 .Returns(questions);
```

Comment: awesome, I'll try this now

Comment: You beat me to the punch. Exactly what I was going to suggest.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu No prob. And about the comment you deleted, you're right, you can skip that step and mock `i => i.QuestionsRepository.GetAll()` directly. Moq will create the intermediary mock for the repo. I think (and I may be wrong here) that this doesn't work in all scenarios though.

Comment: I came to realize what you did later. It's a bit more clear using your approach.

Answer (score 1):

The Where() and ToList() included in the setup is causing the error. Have you tried without it?

```
uwork.Setup(i => i.QuestionsRepository.GetAll()).Returns(questions);
```

What are you trying to do exactly?